# Strange behavior when appending dictionary to list

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am reading JSON into my script and building a list consisting of dictionaries.

My JSON:

```
{
    "JMF": {
        "table1": {
          "email": "JMF1@fake.com",
          "guests": [
            "test1",
            "test2"
          ]
        },
        "table2": {
          "email": "JMF2@fake.com",
          "guests": [
            "test3"
          ]
        }
    },
    "JMC": {
      "table3": {
        "email": "JMC1@fake.com",
        "guests": [
          "test11"
        ]
      }
    },
    "JMD": {
      "table4": {
        "email": "JMD1@fake.com",
        "guests": [
          "test12"
        ]
      },
      "table5": {
        "email": "JMD2@fake.com",
        "guests": [
          "test17"
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

My code:

```
def get_json():
    userinfo_list = []
    with open('guest_users.json') as json_file:
        json_file = json.load(json_file)
        keys = json_file.keys()
        for key in keys:
            userinfo = {}
            for table_key in json_file[key].keys():
                email = json_file[key][table_key]['email']
                users_dict = {}
                users_list = []
                for user in json_file[key][table_key]['guests']:
                    users_dict['username'] = user
                    users_dict['password'] = generate_password()
                    users_list.append(users_dict)
                userinfo['company'] = key
                userinfo['email'] = email
                userinfo['userinfo'] = users_list
                userinfo_list.append(userinfo)
                print(userinfo)
                print(userinfo_list)
```

The problem is that the values in `userinfo_list` get overwritten as soon as my JSON has two sub-keys (`table*`).

This is the output I get, which doesn't make sense:

```
{'userinfo': [{'username': 'test11', 'password': '1fEAg0'}], 'email': 'JMC1@fake.com', 'company': 'JMC'}
[{'userinfo': [{'username': 'test11', 'password': '1fEAg0'}], 'email': 'JMC1@fake.com', 'company': 'JMC'}]
{'userinfo': [{'username': 'test17', 'password': 'A8Jue5'}], 'email': 'JMD2@fake.com', 'company': 'JMD'}
[{'userinfo': [{'username': 'test11', 'password': '1fEAg0'}], 'email': 'JMC1@fake.com', 'company': 'JMC'}, {'userinfo': [{'username': 'test17', 'password': 'A8Jue5'}], 'email': 'JMD2@fake.com', 'company': 'JMD'}]
{'userinfo': [{'username': 'test12', 'password': '0JSpc0'}], 'email': 'JMD1@fake.com', 'company': 'JMD'}
[{'userinfo': [{'username': 'test11', 'password': '1fEAg0'}], 'email': 'JMC1@fake.com', 'company': 'JMC'}, {'userinfo': [{'username': 'test12', 'password': '0JSpc0'}], 'email': 'JMD1@fake.com', 'company': 'JMD'}, {'userinfo': [{'username': 'test12', 'password': '0JSpc0'}], 'email': 'JMD1@fake.com', 'company': 'JMD'}]
{'userinfo': [{'username': 'test2', 'password': 'GagQ59'}, {'username': 'test2', 'password': 'GagQ59'}], 'email': 'JMF1@fake.com', 'company': 'JMF'}
[{'userinfo': [{'username': 'test11', 'password': '1fEAg0'}], 'email': 'JMC1@fake.com', 'company': 'JMC'}, {'userinfo': [{'username': 'test12', 'password': '0JSpc0'}], 'email': 'JMD1@fake.com', 'company': 'JMD'}, {'userinfo': [{'username': 'test12', 'password': '0JSpc0'}], 'email': 'JMD1@fake.com', 'company': 'JMD'}, {'userinfo': [{'username': 'test2', 'password': 'GagQ59'}, {'username': 'test2', 'password': 'GagQ59'}], 'email': 'JMF1@fake.com', 'company': 'JMF'}]
{'userinfo': [{'username': 'test3', 'password': 'U9gP0j'}], 'email': 'JMF2@fake.com', 'company': 'JMF'}
[{'userinfo': [{'username': 'test11', 'password': '1fEAg0'}], 'email': 'JMC1@fake.com', 'company': 'JMC'}, {'userinfo': [{'username': 'test12', 'password': '0JSpc0'}], 'email': 'JMD1@fake.com', 'company': 'JMD'}, {'userinfo': [{'username': 'test12', 'password': '0JSpc0'}], 'email': 'JMD1@fake.com', 'company': 'JMD'}, {'userinfo': [{'username': 'test3', 'password': 'U9gP0j'}], 'email': 'JMF2@fake.com', 'company': 'JMF'}, {'userinfo': [{'username': 'test3', 'password': 'U9gP0j'}], 'email': 'JMF2@fake.com', 'company': 'JMF'}]
```

Comment: Don't overwrite data. Always try to create new lists, new dicts, new everything - if the RAM memory allows you to - and it will allow you to in 99% of the cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are re-appending the *same single dictionary* each iteration:

```
users_dict = {}  # only one copy of this dictionary is ever created
users_list = []
for user in json_file[key][table_key]['guests']:
    users_dict['username'] = user
    users_dict['password'] = generate_password()
    users_list.append(users_dict)  # appending a reference to users_dict
```

Appending does *not* create a copy, so you get multiple references to the same dictionary, and you'll only see the last change reflected. You make the same mistake with the `userinfo` dictionary.

Create a new dictionary *in* the loop:

```
users_list = []
for user in json_file[key][table_key]['guests']:
    users_dict = {}
    users_dict['username'] = user
    users_dict['password'] = generate_password()
    users_list.append(users_dict)
```

You can just specify the key-value pairs directly when creating the dictionary:

```
users_list = []
for user in json_file[key][table_key]['guests']:
    users_dict = {
        'username': user,
        'password': generate_password()
    }
    users_list.append(users_dict)
```

and this can be simplified with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to:

```
users_list = [{'username': user, 'password': generate_password()}
              for user in json_file[key][table_key]['guests']]
```

Note that you don't need to call `dict.keys()` to loop over a dictionary. You can loop *directly* over the dictionary with the exact same results. You probably want to loop over `.items()` instead and avoid having to look up the value for the key each time, and use `.values()` when you don't actually need the key at all:

```
userinfo_list = []
for company, db in json_file.items():
    for table in db.values():
        userinfo = {
            'company': company,
            'email': table['email'],
            'userinfo': [
                {'username': user, 'password': generate_password()}
                for user in table['guests']]
        }
        userinfo_list.append(userinfo)
```

The creation of dictionaries per table per company can also be replaced by a list comprehension, but at this point sticking to nested `for` loops is probably going to be easier to comprehend for future readers.

The above now produces:

```
[{'company': 'JMF',
  'email': 'JMF1@fake.com',
  'userinfo': [{'password': 'random_password_really', 'username': 'test1'},
               {'password': 'random_password_really', 'username': 'test2'}]},
 {'company': 'JMF',
  'email': 'JMF2@fake.com',
  'userinfo': [{'password': 'random_password_really', 'username': 'test3'}]},
 {'company': 'JMC',
  'email': 'JMC1@fake.com',
  'userinfo': [{'password': 'random_password_really', 'username': 'test11'}]},
 {'company': 'JMD',
  'email': 'JMD1@fake.com',
  'userinfo': [{'password': 'random_password_really', 'username': 'test12'}]},
 {'company': 'JMD',
  'email': 'JMD2@fake.com',
  'userinfo': [{'password': 'random_password_really', 'username': 'test17'}]}]
```

from your sample data (and my own definition of `generate_password()`).

Comment: this works perfectly, but I was unable to adapt your code to my updated JSON. Please see my original post for updated JSON.

Comment: @ou_snaaksie: that would normally be a new question. You need to filter the keys of each `db` dictionary here: `for tablename, table in db.items():`, `if not tablename.startswith('table'): continue` (instead of the current `for table in db.values():` loop) would skip any key that doesn't start with `'table'`, like `'lang'`.